# Discord.js Reposting an embed's image with a new link

Tags: javascript, image, bots, discord, discord.js

I need a way to reupload a discord embed's image to post it myself as the thumbnail. I want to delete the original bot's message and use my message as the spawn message instead, sort of as a "shortmode" kind of thing. The problem is that when I delete the original post, the image is also lost and my shortmode repost does not load the image. I have tried adding a delay too but it's not ideal and looks a little ugly. How can I take a discord embed image, download it, and reupload the same image as a thumbnail? Here is the full code, but I will be redacting some irrelevant info:

```
    if (message.author.id == botid && message.guild.id == guild2) {
      message.embeds.forEach((e) => {
        if (e.title !== undefined && e.title.startsWith("The Dungeon")) {
          if (e.image) {

            let url = e.image.url;
            let desc = e.description;
            request(url, async function(err, res, body) {
              if (err !== null) return;
            
              imghash
                .hash(body)
               .then(async (hash) => {
                  let rareresult = raresdb[hash];
                  let notify = notifydb[message.guild.id];
                  if (rareresult === undefined) {
                    let result = db[hash];
                    if (result === undefined) {
                      embed
                        .setTitle("What is this?")
                        .setThumbnail(url)
                        .setColor("0xE91447")")
                      console.log(something here);
                      client.log(something here);
                      return message.channel.send(embed)
                    }
                
                      const args = e.footer.text.split(' ');
                      const prefix = args[10].split('verse');
                      embed
                        .setTitle("You encountered a wild " + result + "!")
                        .setThumbnail(url)
                        .setDescription(desc)
                        .setFooter("Type "+ prefix[0] +"wish " + result + " to find! ")
                      message.channel.send(embed)
                      console.log(something here);
                      //await delay(777);
                     // message.delete(e)
                   return client.log(something here);
                  }
                  
                  if (notify === undefined) {
                      const args = e.footer.text.split(' ');
                      const prefix = args[10].split('verse');
                      embed
                        .setTitle("You spotted " + rareresult + "!")
                        .setThumbnail(url)
                        .setDescription(desc)
                        .setFooter("Type "+ prefix[0] +"wish " + rareresult + " to find!")
                      message.channel.send(embed)

                     // await delay(666);
                      //message.delete(e)
                    client.log(something here);
                    return console.log(something here);
                  };

                  message.channel.send(notify + "**" + rareresult + "** happened!");
                      const args = e.footer.text.split(' ');
                      const prefix = args[10].split('verse');
                      embed
                        .setTitle("You found " + rareresult + "!")
                        .setThumbnail(url)
                        .setDescription(desc)
                       .setFooter("Type "+ prefix[0] +"wish " + rareresult + " to find! ")
                      message.channel.send(embed)

                  let cnt = message.content
                    if (cnt !== " ") {
                    message.pin(0) // ?
                  }
                
                  client.log(something here);
                  console.log(something here);
                })
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

My previous question might not have been clear given that I did not provide the entire code block. But to reiterate, I want to repost `e.image.url` as `.setThumbnail(url)` with my own source of the `url` instead of using the exact same one, since it doesn't load when I delete the original message. So how can I use the exact same image from `e.image.url` but simply reuploaded so that the link is different?

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? Whats wrong with this question?

Comment: You should try to explain your code a little bit more, as it's quite an heavy block you sent

Comment: @Tenclea last time I asked a person said I didn't provide enough. My code is meant to read a message from a bot's embed, and send it's own message with the only difference being that the `image` from the original bot's embed would be placed in my `thumbnail` area, while deleting the original bot's message completely. There is more going on there, such as identifying the picture using a hashing method, but my question is about how I can save/download the `e.embed.url` and reupload for use in `.setThumbnail(url). Or whatever other function that could allow me to respost the image.

Comment: Basically the important portion for my questions is `let url = e.image.url;` and `.setThumbnail(url)`. I want to use the "same" image as my thumbnail, but a new version of it. Essentially reposting the image myself instead of using the same exact link, as it doesn't load if I try to delete the original bot's message.